# SIMPLE HTML DOM memory leak

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a script using simple_html_dom.

```
foreach ($urls as $url)
    {
       $html = file_get_html($url);

        if($html->innertext!=''){

            foreach($html->find('.doc div[style="padding-top:1px;border-bottom:1px solid #eaeaec;padding-bottom:6px;"]') as $b){
                $b->style='""';
                echo $b;
            }           
            }
        $html->clear();
        unset($html); 
    }
```

When I running this script I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 444596224 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1272 bytes).

Comment: The size of the HTML file you're loading is probably too large.

Comment: That's like 400 MB,.. cannot imagine html/dom operations taking so much memory.

Comment: Try different url, to confirm what @nickb supposed. Some small-sized page

Comment: After that, try downloading the page using cURL instead before using the output with simple_html_dom... I personally had many issues with `file_get_html` as well as many others (according to google)

Comment: I suppose the problem to be in your selector. Try doing something more simple like selecting by class or any other attribute.

Comment: Yes, file is big ~5mb. If I parse smaller file, then all works fine. But what can I do to parse this big file?

Answer (score 4):

> Q: This script is leaking memory seriously... After it finished
>   running, it's not cleaning up dom object properly from memory..
>
> A: Due to php5 circular references memory leak, after creating DOM
>   object, you must call $dom->clear() to free memory if call
>   file_get_dom() more then once.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $html = file_get_html(...); 
> // do something... 
> $html->clear(); 
> unset($html);
> ```

Taken from their FAQ found here:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_faq.htm

Answer (score 0):

if you still want to parse this file

you can set your php.ini's `memory_limit` higher or use below code.

`ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`

or optimize your code : (when found that, release it)

```
    $finder = $html->find('.doc div[style="..."]');

    foreach($finder as $index => $b){
        /* do something here */
        $finder[$index]->clear();
    }
    $html->clear();
```

maybe you can use REGEX remove or get what you need

Answer (score 0):

for fix problem need to replace this function，

```
function clear(){
    $this->dom = null;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->children = null;
}
```

on this:

```
function clear(){
    unset($this->dom);
    unset($this->parent);
    unset($this->parent);
    unset($this->children);
}
```